# How should I read 帖合・書店印 and what is it?

Tags: word-choice, kanji, culture

> 帖合・書店印

There are cards in my books called 注文カード and it's written on them. I can't type the first word automatically and I don't know how to read 印 since it has two pronunciations: しるし, いん.

ちょうあい・しょてんいん?

---

I've found 帖合 on Jisho, but I don't understand exactly what it is. I haven't found it on Weblio. On Google, I've seen there's a question about it on Yahoo!, but I can't see the website and the rest is all in Chinese.

Comment: What kind of research have you tried to do? Did you search for it?

Comment: I understand this is a reasonably difficult and interesting question, but as a rule of this site, please always include your research effort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

帖 and 帳 are interchangeable kanji when they refer to  notebook/journal/logbook. For example, [手帳 and 手帖](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%89%8B%E5%B8%B3) refer to exactly the same thing. For a certain historical reason, 帳 is more common almost everywhere now, but 帖 is still sometimes used.

So 帖合 is the same as 帳合 (ちょうあい), which you should be able to find in any dictionary. However, this is not the end of the story.

The dictionary definition of 帳合/帖合 is "(financial) reconciliation", i.e., the process of verifying the accuracy of data by comparing two account books. However, in business fields, its meaning has been extended several times:

1. reconciliation
2. account keeping or sales management in general
3. (being) business partners

   > ###### [帳合とは？サプライチェーンの効率性が高まる？徹底解説します！](https://diamond-rm.net/glossary/75091/)
   >
   > 取引の口座が開かれている、基本取引契約が結ばれている、あるいは仕入や販売の取引実績や履歴が残っている状態を「帳合関係がある」という。
4. [in publishing jargon] distributing/wholesaler companies (cf. [出版取次会社](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%87%BA%E7%89%88%E5%8F%96%E6%AC%A1))

   > ###### [出版業界の豆知識](http://www.1book.co.jp/000883.html)
   >
   > 帳合とは: 書店から見て本の仕入先となる**取次会社のこと**です。本来は帳簿の付け合わせをすることから帳合と言われています。出版業界では、「総合取次」と「専門取次」と大きく２つの取次に分かれることから、「帳合はどこですか？」などといった使い方をしています。

In your case, 帖合 specifically refers to distributing/wholesaler companies such as トーハン and 日本出版販売. "帖合・書店印" means "stamp of the distributer or the bookstore (retailer)". 印 is always read いん when it refers to a seal/stamp.

For those who are curious what a 注文カード is, see [this](http://pro.bookoffonline.co.jp/book-enjoy/books-trivia/20160430-books-slip.html).